# Thymeleaf: create custom sections in default.html

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Previously I have worked just with JSP and Apache Tiles and now I'm trying to create Thymeleaf template for the first time. The problem I faced is that I have no idea how to insert custom header, footer and other sections into default.html. Here is the code example.

default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Default template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/app.css" th:href="@{/css/app.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/myCss.css" th:href="@{/css/myCss.css}"/>
</head>
<body>

<header id="header" layout:fragment="header">
    HEADER
</header>

<section id="sidemenu" layout:fragment="sideMenu">
    SIDE_MENU
</section>

<section id="site-content" layout:fragment="siteContent"></section>

<footer id="footer" layout:fragment="footerTemplate"></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

In default.html I have 'siteContent' which is provided for inserting all of application's html files, and 'header', 'sideMenu' and 'footer' sections that have to be implemented in separate corresponding html files (templates) and inserted into default.html.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="default">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="siteContent">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{default}">
<head>
    <title>Footer Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="footer">
    Copyright © 2017
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is an example of footer.

SiteContent area works fine. Footer's 'Copyright © 2017' is supposed to be imported into default.html's footer area, but it doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found: I should have used 
'footer id="footer" layout:include="footerTemplate"' 
instead of 
'footer id="footer" layout:fragment="footerTemplate"'

By the way, the examples, listed on [thymeleaf's website](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) never worked, but the correct decision wasn't there.